# Loading a Javascript Class once

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following problem.

Im using a file with this javascript class

```
class Options {
    constructor (a, b, c) {
        this._a = a;
    }
}
```

Im now including a partialview via Ajax, where a script import tag using the option class.

Now i have the following problem that im load different partial views with the same option class and i only want to include the option class when its need by the partial view.

So here is the question is there a way to tell javascript if this class is already defined than do not define it again. 
In Chrome i get the Error that im inluding the class twice

> Identifier 'Options' has already been declared

Im searching for something like this:

```
<script src="Options" include_once></script>
```

Comment: partialview is an ASP.NET thing right?

Comment: yes it is. but here you can ignore it. cause the backend isn't meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var Options = Options || class {
 //...
 };
```

This won't override the existing class.

Comment: that looks nice, but i need it global.

Comment: @thorsten this *is* global.

Comment: why do you write something like this? for me it is not!